# Unexpected Token ["default"] when using default component imports in React Native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm creating a project using React Native and TypeScript. When I try to import a default component from a third party library, I get a syntax error because of how the token gets built with JSX:

```
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image';

export const Component = () => <FastImage />
```

When this ultimately runs it turns into

```
<react_native_fast_image_1["default"]
```

This is a syntax error because of the `[` in JSX.

I'm using https://github.com/ds300/react-native-typescript-transformer as a transformer for TypeScript and React Native without any additional settings or configuration.

Is there a way to transform the JSX output for React Native using TypeScript to avoid this syntax error?

Comment: my question is why dont you just use FastImage where you need it instead of importing it to export it.

Comment: This is just an example to reproduce the problem.